# Unable to properly login

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, wp-redirect

First of all, sorry if the question is not clear the first time, it's a bit tricky to explain.

Here's the issue i've got:

I have a website running locally with mamp pro.

Site name is `dev.site` (the database wp-option uses the correct name)

The site looks and works fine, but the issue happens when i try to login.

I type in `dev.site/wp-admin` and i get a 404 page not found. This is strange but i decided to try also `wp-login.php`

This seems to work (altough without style) but after the login the url looks like this:

```
http://dev.site/wp-admin/dev.site/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.site%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

which to me looks wrong (`dev.site/wp-admin/dev.site/...`)?

I've tried everything (deleted .htaccess and created a new one, copied new files from a fresh wordpress zip into the folder to override the old ones, disabled plugins and so on) but i don't know why this happens and what can be the cause. Any suggestion?

For what i know the redirect url should be wp-admin straight away and not that mess i was mentioning above.

Hope this explanation is clear enought and thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL in the wp-options table (in two places) needs to include the protocol - the 'http://' or the 'https://' part. That's why, I believe, you are getting the double 'dev.site' in your URLs.

That's the first think I would check.

Comment: Ahh good point! Thanks